# Setting width and height of the video

Tags: html, css

I am facing a problem regarding the width and height of the video. Right now, it is occupying full screen but i want it to be full sized in width and setting height as I want. For example, refer http://airbnb.com. If anybody could help me out. Thanks

```
<div align="center">
<video autoplay loop id="video" class="con">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
<div class="overlay">
    <form>
        <label for="input">Form Input Label</label>
        <input id="input" name="input" value="" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the css I am using.

```
.con {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
width: auto;
height: auto;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transition: 1s opacity;
}

.overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
}
```

Comment: There is a issue of ratio of height and width in this video. If I reduce its height to 70% its width also reduces.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to make the width of the video wider than the height. Just change the min-height to something like 50%.

Answer (score 0):

the video tag has width and height attribut, so basically you can use this one :

```
<video autoplay loop id="video" class="con" width="320" height="240">
    <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
</video>
```

see more on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp)

and based on your css style, one thing you need is to reduce the min-height to something like 70% or whatever you want.

Comment: it goes full screen. its not setting the height to 70%

Comment: i tried your code, it works fine, just remove the min-height. see this fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/kfqe7vgw/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/kfqe7vgw/1/)

Comment: Even if I remove min-height, it still displays as full screnn

Comment: Chan need the video full screen fit with the browser viewport.

Comment: @fiido...Width wise full screen.. but height wise half or may be less than that.. i guess the issue is with aspect ratio

Comment: how about set the max-height: 50%; ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the min-width:auto;

I think this will work for you.